# GStreamer: get video from RTP, setting the format automatically

Tags: c++, gstreamer

Let's say I've got a simple RTP video server:

```
ximagesrc ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=500 speed-preset=slow ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

And I'm receiving it just fine:

```
udpsrc port=5000 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

But if my server was sending H265 (or any other format), I'd have to use another pipeline. Considering there are a ton of possible formats, that is definitely something I'd like to avoid. Is there any way to get my video decoded from any format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. RTP streams are supposed to be initiated by SDP and RTSP control protocols which will tell you what kind of stream you are dealing with. If you want self describing media, perhaps try looking at MPEG-TS instead.